# Strange Angular Error 'unknown provider'

Tags: angularjs, cookies, dependency-injection, dependencies, angularjs-injector

To whom it may concern,

My app suddenly stopped rendering because of this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies <- $cookieStore <- authInterceptor <- $http <- Auth <- $cookies
```

[Here's the link to AngularJs docs for more informations about this error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProv%E2%80%A60%3C-%20authInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20Auth%20%3C-%20%24cookies%22)

The only thing I can manage to understand from this error is that $cookies are unknown to the browser? WTF would that even mean.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Check your `app.module` defination. Verify that you have listed all your dependencies in your main/index.html file. Also check for any typo in module declaration.

Comment: You are injecting an unknown module. Is its file present and linked in the app?

Comment: please share your app.module file

Comment: Hi all -- sorry for such an insular question. Long story short: I think I installed some dependencies, i.e. flow.js, etc, that confused my app and, more importantly, confused me. I ended up scaffolding the app again and doing a lot of copying and pasting of my own code and things are back to normal.